# Rails ancestry gem + Render and choose category/subcategory in new form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, simple-form, ancestry

I have Rails 5.2.2 and I'm trying to implement the ancestry gem.

So what I want:

I want a user to create an offer for an automotive part, but in the new form I want to be able to choose the category/subcategories and then enter the other details that I have, and then submit the form to create the offer. Let's say that someone wants to add for selling Brake Pads.
But first has to select the parent categories.
E.g

Car **->** Brakes **->** Brake Pads

So after choosing Brake Pads, he can create the offer.

What I have:

```
#category.rb
class Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_ancestry
  has_many :parts
end
```

-

```
#part.rb
class Part < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :category
end
```

For now, I have already created one in the console just to make it work:
Eg

```
car = Category.create!(name: "Car")
brakes = Category.create!(name: "Brakes", parent: car)
brake_pads = Category.create!(name: "Brake Pads", parent: brakes)
```

I already also run the migration `rails g migration add_category_to_parts category:references`.

And my view:

```
#views/parts/new.html.haml
.container
  %h2.center Create offer
  = simple_form_for(@part, html: {class: "form-group" }) do |f|
    .form-group.col-md-8.col-md-offset-2.well
      = f.input :title
      = f.input :make_name, label: "Make"
      = f.input :code, label: 'Part number'
      = f.association :condition, label_method: :name, prompt: "-"
      = f.input :description
      .form-actions
        = f.button :submit, class: "btn btn-primary btn-dark-blue"
```

The question is: 
How I can render the categories/subcategories in my views-> parts -> new.html.haml form with 3 dropdowns(one for each subcategory because I will have many categories/subcategories) so the user can choose them and then create the offer?

Comment: What is your reasoning for not wanting to create a categories controller? While you can manually set categories via seeds or the console, a Category should be treated as it's own resource (in my opinion).

Comment: Hi Mark, thank you very much for your reply. I thought because I will create the categories once I don't need the controller for something else, but I will create one. (I edited my question: I want to render the categories/subcategories in views->parts-> new.html.haml). If I create the categories controller, do you know how to render these at parts new form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need CategoriesController in any case, because you need dependent dropdowns here. When user selects category in the first one, you need to make AJAX request to get subcategories and so on

```
# config/routes.rb
resources :categories, only: [] do
  get :select_item, on: :collection
end

# app/assets/javascripts/application.js
$('#first-dropdown').on('change', function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'categories/select_item?category_id=' + $(this).val(),
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
      var childElement = $('#second-dropdown');
      childElement.html('');
      data.forEach(function(v) {
        var id = v.id;
        var name = v.name;
        childElement.append('<option value="' + id + '">' + name + '</option>');
      });
    }
  });
});

# app/controllers/categories_controller.rb
Class CategoriesController < ApplicationController
  def select_item
    category = @category.find params[:category_id]
    render json: category.children
  end
end 

# app/inputs/fake_select_input.rb
class FakeSelectInput < SimpleForm::Inputs::CollectionSelectInput
  def input(wrapper_options = nil)
    label_method, value_method = detect_collection_methods

    merged_input_options = merge_wrapper_options(input_html_options, wrapper_options).merge(input_options.slice(:multiple, :include_blank, :disabled, :prompt))

    template.select_tag(
      attribute_name, 
      template.options_from_collection_for_select(collection, value_method, label_method, selected: input_options[:selected], disabled: input_options[:disabled]), 
      merged_input_options
    )
  end
end

# views/parts/new.html.haml
.form-group.col-md-8.col-md-offset-2.well
  = f.input :title
  = f.input :make_name, label: "Make"
  = f.input :code, label: 'Part number'
  = f.association :condition, label_method: :name, prompt: "-"
  = f.input :description
  = f.input :parent_category_id, as: :fake_select, collection: Category.roots, input_html: { id: 'first-dropdown' }
  = f.input category_id, collection: [], input_html: { id: 'second-dropdown' }
  .form-actions
    = f.button :submit, class: "btn btn-primary btn-dark-blue"
```

Since simple_form relies on using a model you need to create custom input for non-model fields (parent categories). You need to save only one category_id to @part, parent categories can always be taken from it.
If you need more, than 2 dropdowns, just add one more function or (better) change it, so you can pass dependent dropdown as a parameter

Comment: Vasilisa thank you very much for the answer. The problem now is that the first dropdown contains all the categories/subcategories and the second dropdown is blank

Comment: @Stefanos, it should be `Category.roots` instead of `Category.all` for first select. And second select should be blank until you make a selection in the first one, am I right?

Comment: Vasilisa(for some reason the @name doesn't work), for the first element I changed the 'Category.all` to `Category.roots` as you said and it works perfect and contains only the categories. For the second dropdown you are right, it should be blank until I make a category selection in the first one, but now that the first works exactly as I want with your solution, the second is still blank, even if I choose a category in the first dropdown.  **Thank you so much for your time and your help**, but I am still learning RoR because I like it veeery much ;)

Comment: @Stefanos, do you js debugging skills? You need to check with `console.log` if `$(this).val()` and `data` from server are correct. And what do you have in server logs in `select_item` action?

Comment: Vasilisa I don't know js and this is the reason that I can't make it work, I can make it work perferct with single dropdown but I want something better like your solution. I open the console and have some errors in the js code and specifically at this line `('<option value="' + id '">' + name + '</option>');`, but sorry I have no idea about js. If you copy the code in a js validator I think for you maybe you solve it immediately. It says about syntax error

Comment: @Stefanos, fixed typos in js

Comment: Thanks! Now I don't have errors from js but I am trying to submit the form to see the errors in my server logs and says that `SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" WHERE "categories"."ancestry" IS NULL
  ↳ app/inputs/fake_select_input.rb:3`. If I am wasting your time I don't want to do that no more, your help is already enough ;)

Comment: @Stefanos, it becomes interesting for me, but remote debugging isn't easy :) Changes `routes.rb` and js part again - you need to pass proper params to the controller

Comment: Vasilisa, stll the same errors, the second dropdown is still blank after choosing category and same error at server log. I know that isn't easy and you wasted much of your time to help me and I appreciate that. And you are the only one (so many developers here) that tried to help me at this very complicated problem for me and I am stuck so many days now at this problem. But you solved the most of my problem so I will accept your answer and I will try to solve the rest with some way. Thank you very much again

Comment: You're welcome :) Maybe it is better if you create a new question if you can't solve all problems